# Google Apps Script not sending emails (except internally delivered)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-contacts-api

Let me start by thanking anyone who tries to help. Now, the issue:

I have a script that does the following (well, not really, because the first part is failing):

- **Part 1:** it checks all contacts in a given group/label in Google Contacts and sends an email to each of those contacts. This is the part that is failing!
- **Part 2:** Generates a Form (when deployed as Web App) where each contact can enter the updated contact details.
- **Part 3:** The submitted contact details update the existing contact on the sender's Google Contacts.

When I run the script (using the "initialize" function) I receive an email on my personal account linked (as a recovery and secondary email) to work account (because it's delivered locally, not sent using SMTP, as clearly proved by the message header), but no other contact in the group receives the email. Since this is the only part failing I guess the issue must be related to the "GmailApp.sendEmail" function (although it might be related to some issue with getting the contacts in the specified group), but so far, after days troubleshooting this, I wasn't able to find a solution... :-(

If someone can help I'd be very grateful. And a thousand thanks in advance!

**QUICK UPDATE: 
So, I found a way to test the results and it seems the issue is related to my Google Contacts contacts. The output of Contacts[i].getPrimaryEmail() shows all but one contact (the one with my recovery email) as null:**

contacts

null
null
null
nuno*******da@gmail.com
null
null
null

**Script files "Code.gs" and "form.html" content attached.**

---

```js
function Initialize() {
  
  var NAME  = "Mark Twain";           // It will show up in the signature of your outgoing emails
  var CONTACTGROUP = "Test1";     // Enter the exact name of your Google Contacts group 
  var SIGNATURE = '<a href="https://www.sopimat.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/V9jjDkc/sopimat-signature-png-1.png" alt="Sopimat" border="0" class="center"></a>';
  
  
  
  try {
    var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup(CONTACTGROUP);
    
    if (group) {
      
      var emailSUBJECT  = "Your contact information";    
      var Contacts = group.getContacts();
      
      for (i=0; i<Contacts.length; i++) {
        
        var email = Contacts[i].getPrimaryEmail();
        
        
        
        if (email && email.length) {
          
          var ID = Contacts[i].getId();
          ID = ID.substr(ID.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
          
          var emailBody = "Hi,<br /><br />" +
            "We created a Form using Google Scripts to let our contacts update their own contact information on our Google Contacts database, in order to keep all the details updated and make sure that you receive all the necessary information from us.<br /><br />Please take a moment to update your contact information in my address book.<br /><br />" + 
              "To proceed, <a href='" + ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + "?id=" + 
                ID + "'>click here</a> to open the form and fill-in your updated contact details. " +
                  "Your information will be automatically added to my Google Contacts." + "<br /><br />" + "<a href='" + ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + "?id=" + 
                ID + "'><b>Go to Form ►►</b></a>" +
                    "<br /><br />Thanks,<br />" + NAME + "<br /><br />" + SIGNATURE;
          
          GmailApp.sendEmail(email, emailSUBJECT, emailBody, 
                             {htmlBody:emailBody, name:NAME});
        }
      }
    }   
  } catch (e) {
    throw e.toString();
  }
}

function doGet(e) {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("form.html");
  html.id = e.parameter.id;
  var contact = GetBasicContact(e.parameter.id);
  html.email = contact.EMAIL;
  html.name = contact.NAME;
  return html.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function GetBasicContact(id) {    
    
  var contact = {};
  
  contact.NAME = "";
  contact.EMAIL = "";

  id = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/" + encodeURIComponent(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) + "/base/" + id; 
  
  var c = ContactsApp.getContactById(id);    
  
  if (c) {
    
    if (c.getFullName().length)
      contact.NAME = c.getFullName();
    
    if(c.getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL).length)
      contact.EMAIL = c.getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL)[0].getAddress();
    
  }    
  
  return contact;
  
}

function GetContact(id) {    
    
  var contact = {};  
  
  contact.FOUND = 0;
  contact.id = id;
  
  try {
    
    var c = ContactsApp.getContactById(id);    
    
    if (c) {
            
      contact.FOUND = 1;
      
      if (c.getFullName().length)
        contact.FULL_NAME = c.getFullName();
      
      if(c.getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL).length)
        contact.HOME_EMAIL = c.getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL)[0].getAddress();

      if(c.getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE).length)
        contact.MOBILE_PHONE = c.getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE)[0].getPhoneNumber();
      
      if(c.getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS).length) {
        contact.HOME_ADDRESS = c.getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS)[0].getAddress();
        contact.HOME_ADDRESS = contact.HOME_ADDRESS.replace(/\n/g, ", ");
      }
      
      if(c.getIMs(ContactsApp.Field.SKYPE).length)
        contact.SKYPE = c.getIMs(ContactsApp.Field.SKYPE)[0].getAddress();
            
      if(c.getUrls(ContactsApp.Field.BLOG).length)
        contact.BLOG = c.getUrls(ContactsApp.Field.BLOG)[0].getAddress();
      
      if(c.getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY).length) {
        var months = ["0", "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", 
                      "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];
        contact.BIRTHDAY = months.indexOf(c.getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY)[0].getMonth().toString()) +
          "/" + c.getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY)[0].getDay() +
          "/" + c.getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY)[0].getYear();
      }      
    }    
    
    return contact;
  
  } catch (e) {
  
    return contact;    
  
  }  
  
}


function UpdateContact(contact) {    
  
  try {   
            
    var cid = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/" + encodeURIComponent(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) + "/base/" + contact.id; 
    
    var c = ContactsApp.getContactById(cid);    
    
    if (c) { 
                  
      c.setFullName(contact.FULL_NAME);
            
      if(c.getIMs(ContactsApp.Field.SKYPE).length)
        c.getIMs(ContactsApp.Field.SKYPE)[0].deleteIMField();
      
      if (contact.SKYPE.length)
        c.addIM(ContactsApp.Field.SKYPE, contact.SKYPE);   
      
      if (c.getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS).length)
        c.getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS)[0].deleteAddressField();
      
      if (contact.HOME_ADDRESS.length)
        c.addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS, contact.HOME_ADDRESS);
      
      if (c.getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE).length)
        c.getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE)[0].deletePhoneField();
      
      if (contact.MOBILE_PHONE.length)
        c.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, contact.MOBILE_PHONE);
      
      if (c.getUrls(ContactsApp.Field.BLOG).length)
        c.getUrls(ContactsApp.Field.BLOG)[0].deleteUrlField();
      
      if (contact.BLOG.length)
        c.addUrl(ContactsApp.Field.BLOG, contact.BLOG);     
      
      if(contact.TWITTER.length) { 
        var cfields = c.getCustomFields();
        for (var i = 0; i < cfields.length; i++) {
          if (cfields[i].getLabel() == 'Twitter') {
            cfields[i].deleteCustomField();
          }
        }
        c.addCustomField("Twitter", "https://twitter.com/" + contact.TWITTER);
      }
            
      if (contact.BIRTHDAY.length) {
        
        var months = 
            [ 0, ContactsApp.Month.JANUARY, ContactsApp.Month.FEBRUARY, ContactsApp.Month.MARCH,
             ContactsApp.Month.APRIL, ContactsApp.Month.MAY, ContactsApp.Month.JUNE,
             ContactsApp.Month.JULY, ContactsApp.Month.AUGUST, ContactsApp.Month.SEPTEMBER,
             ContactsApp.Month.OCTOBER, ContactsApp.Month.NOVEMBER, ContactsApp.Month.DECEMBER
            ];
        
        var date = contact.BIRTHDAY.split("/");
        
        if (c.getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY).length)
          c.getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY)[0].deleteDateField();
        
        c.addDate(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY, months[parseFloat(date[0])], parseFloat(date[1]), parseFloat(date[2]));
        
      }
      
      GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),
                        "Updated: " + contact.FULL_NAME + " (" + contact.HOME_EMAIL + ")", 
                        Utilities.jsonStringify(contact));
      
      
    }    
    
  } catch (e) {
    
  }  
  
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <llink rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    
@media screen and (max-width:980px) {
html, body, iframe#sandboxFrame, .full_size {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
body {
    color: #222;
/*    font-size: 2.3vw !important; */
/*    line-height:2.8vw !important; */
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.contacts { 
    width: 95%; 
    margin: auto;  
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 12px;
    } 
    
    h2 {
    color: #000;
/*    font-size: 3.2vw !important; */
/*    line-height:4.2vw !important; */
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px #333 solid;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
/*    margin-bottom: 30px; */
}
    .control-label {
    display: flex;
    min-width: 29%!important;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 3vw !important;
    line-height:3vw !important;
    text-align: left;
    }
    
    input[type="date"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="email"], input[type="month"], input[type="number"], input[type="password"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="text"], input[type="time"], input[type="url"], input[type="week"], select[multiple], select[size], textarea {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #9e9e9e;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #000;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3vw !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: auto;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    float:none;
    height: 65px;
    text-align: left;
}

.button.action, .button.blue, button.action, button.blue, input[type="button"].action, input[type="button"].blue, input[type="submit"].action, input[type="submit"].blue {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    /* background-color: #c42839!important; */
    border: 1px solid #3079ed;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 35%;
    width: 30%;
    border-radius: 55px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3vw !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 30px;
    }

.button, button, input[type="button"], input[type="image"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #333;
    cursor: default;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 27px;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 72px;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0 8px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;    
}
#message {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -10px;
    font: 15px/20px arial, sans-serif !important;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width:981px) {
html, body, iframe#sandboxFrame, .full_size {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.contacts { 
    width: 560px; 
    margin: 0 auto;  
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 12px;
    } 


    h2 {
    color: #000;
    font: 16px/24px arial, sans-serif normal;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px #333 solid;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
    .control-label {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 29%!important;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 15px !important;
    line-height:20px !important;
/*    font: 15px/20px arial, sans-serif; */
    text-align: left;
    }
    
    input[type="date"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="email"], input[type="month"], input[type="number"], input[type="password"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="text"], input[type="time"], input[type="url"], input[type="week"], select[multiple], select[size], textarea {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #000;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 70%;
    float:right;
    text-align: left;
}

.button.action, .button.blue, button.action, button.blue, input[type="button"].action, input[type="button"].blue, input[type="submit"].action, input[type="submit"].blue {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    /* background-color: #c42839!important; */
    border: 1px solid #3079ed;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 37%;
    width: 26%;
    border-radius: 55px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 27px;
}
.button, button, input[type="button"], input[type="image"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #c42839, #c42839);
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #333;
    cursor: default;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 27px;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 72px;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0 8px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#message {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    font: 15px/18px arial, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
}
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  filter: brightness(0.94);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.center_text{
    text-align: center;
}
    </style>

<div class="contacts">
  <h2 class="title">Google Contacts Updater</h2>
  <p id="message">
    Please, fill the form below to update your contact information.<br>Thanks for your cooperation! 
  </p>

  <form id="contactform">
    <p>
      <label class="control-label" for="inputName">Your Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="inputFULL_NAME" placeholder="Full Name" value="<?= name ?>">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email Address</label>
      <input type="text" id="inputHOME_EMAIL" class="input-large" placeholder="i.e.: name@yourdomain.com">
    </p>
    
    <p>  
      <label class="control-label" for="inputMobilePhone">Mobile Phone</label>
      <input type="text" id="inputMOBILE_PHONE" class="input-medium" placeholder="">
    </p>
    
    <p>
      <label class="control-label" for="inputAddressWork">Street Address</label>
      <input type="text" id="inputHOME_ADDRESS" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label class="control-label" for="inputSkype">Skype</label>
      <input type="text" id="inputSKYPE" class="input-small"  placeholder="@username">
    </p>

    <p><label class="control-label" for="inputTwitter">Twitter</label>
      <input type="text" id="inputTWITTER" class="input-small" placeholder="@username">
    </p>  
    
    <p>
      <label class="control-label" for="inputDOB">Birthday</label>
      <input type="text" id="inputBIRTHDAY" class="input-small" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label class="control-label" for="inputBlog">Website</label>
      <input type="text" id="inputBLOG" class="input" placeholder="i.e.: yourwebsite.com">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= id; ?>" />
      <input type="submit" class="btn blue" value="Update Contact" onclick="updateGoogleContacts(); return false;">
    </p>
  </form>
  <hr />
  <p class="center_text">If you have any questions send an email to <a href="mailto:info@testdomain.com?Subject=Google%20Contacts%20Updater%20Script">info@testdomain.com</a></p>

</div>



<script>

  function progress() {
    $("#message").html("Your contact details have been updated. Thanks!");
    return;
  }

  function updateGoogleContacts() {

    var contact = {};

    contact.FULL_NAME    = $("input#inputFULL_NAME").val();
    contact.HOME_EMAIL   = $("input#inputHOME_EMAIL").val();
    contact.HOME_ADDRESS = $("input#inputHOME_ADDRESS").val();
    contact.MOBILE_PHONE = $("input#inputMOBILE_PHONE").val();
    contact.SKYPE        = $("input#inputSKYPE").val();
    contact.TWITTER      = $("input#inputTWITTER").val();
    contact.BLOG         = $("input#inputBLOG").val();
    contact.BIRTHDAY     = $("input#inputBIRTHDAY").val();
    contact.id           = "<?= id ?>";

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(progress).UpdateContact(contact);      

    $("#contactform").hide();
    $("#message").html("Updating your contact...");

    return false;

  }

</script>
```

Comment: "it might be related to some issue with getting the contacts"... this is easy to verify. Have you tried seeing what the values of `Contacts[i].getPrimaryEmail()` are?

Comment: Have you tried to add logging, to see for what values you're trying to send an email?

Comment: You should use var contact instead of var Contacts

Comment: Changing "Contacts" to "contact" has no effect as it simply changing the name of the variable.

Comment: As for Diego's comment: how can I simply check the values returned by Contacts[i].getPrimaryEmail() ?
There's nothing logging this...

If you could detail how to get there it would be perfect. I'm just starting with scripts so any assumption that I know how to achieve something can be wrong... :-D

Comment: **QUICK UPDATE: 
So, I found a way to test the results and it seems the issue is related to my Google Contacts contacts. The output of Contacts[i].getPrimaryEmail() shows all but one contact (the one with my recovery email) as null:**

contacts

null<br>
null<br>
null<br>
nuno*******da@gmail.com<br>
null<br>
null<br>
null<br>